# Linking sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

Here is what I want to do. Sheet one on a workbook is a "master list of all. Sheets 2 thru 5 are location breakdowns of the master list, with column B being the location. I want to be able to change the location on Sheet one and have it populate/depopulate the proper location sheet 2 thru 5

Answer (score 3):

Try using the **INDIRECT** function. See [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a cell on another worksheet using the following format `Sheetname!Cell identifier`. For example:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

You can directly enter this on cells on the other sheets. Or type <kbd>=</kbd> and then select the other sheet and then select the cell you want and then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the referenced cell will be inserted for you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use so called 3D-formula: assuming you need to "populate" cell A1 from sheets 2-5 use this formula: `=SUM(Sheet2:Sheet5!A1)`

Read more: [3d formulas in Excel 2010](http://www.microsofttraining.net/fg-96/3d-formulas-in-excel-2010.html)